Largest root of the Adjacency matrix of two graphs (comparison)
Let $G$ and $H$ be two graphs whose spectral radius (largest eigenvalue) of the adjacency matrix is the largest root of the following polynomial:
$$P_G(x) = x^6-x^5-(2a-n+5)x^4+(2a-n+1)x^3+2(5a-3n+5)x^2-2(3a-2n+2)x-4(3a-2n+2),$$ and
$$P_H(x) = x^6 - (2a-n+6)x^4-2x^3+(10a-6n+13)x^2+4x-2(6a-4n+5).$$
Let the largest root be denoted by $\rho(G)$ and $\rho(H)$, respectively. The domain of $a$ is $\frac{2n}{3} \le a \le n-1$ and $a,n \in \Bbb N.$
Since the adjacency matrix is a non-negative matrix, by the Perron-Frobenius Theorem we have that the largest root is positive.
Using Sage-Math for different values of $a$ and $n$ we have the evidence that $\rho(H)> \rho(G)$.
We were trying to prove it by showing $P_H(x) \le P_G(x)$ for all $x \ge \rho(G)$, but we are stuck in showing $P_G(x) - P_H(x) \ge 0$ for all $x \ge \rho(G)$.

$\textbf{Is there any other method by which we can compare largest root of two polynomials,}$
$\textbf{where the largest root is positive?}$


$P_G-P_H$ is of the form $-x^5$ + lower order terms so for $x$ large it goes to minus infinity.
